# How to change colors programmatically in Konsole based on current directory?

Tags: linux, shell, kde-plasma, konsole

I currently use a color scheme based on which directory that I'm working in.  I manually open up a Konsole shell and then cd into a directory and got to Settings and change the color scheme.

What I would like to do is have Konsole automatically set its foreground and background colors based on which directory I'm in.  Basically if I'm in any subdirectory below /home/me/src/java then I would like to use text white, background blue, for example.  If I'm below /home/me/src/documentation I want text black, background white, for example.  I would like the color change to occur automatically, programmatically, when I call the "cd" command.

Is this possible?  If so, can you provide me some direction as to how?

The way I see it I will need to be able to do a couple of things:

- Be able to detect which Konsole the shell process (bash) is running in.
- Be able to tell Konsole, probably via API call, to change the color scheme on the fly.

Comment: If this involves me programming to APIs then it is a programming issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you started, [here](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdebase-apps/konsole/scripting.html)'s a little information about using D-Bus to script Konsole.

You don't say which shell you're using, but if it's Bash you may want to use the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable which holds a command to be executed each time the $PS1 prompt is issued. The Z shell has a similar facility that's probably a bit more powerful (see `man zshmisc` for `chpwd` and `precmd`).

Otherwise, you might be able to use [xterm escape sequences](http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html).

Answer (score 2):

#### Context

Actually, Konsole has support for what they profiles. A profile is a group of settings (not only background), which you can manually define under `Settings | Manage Profiles` and around.

Also, there exists a command line utility called `konsoleprofile` which allows for programmatic changing of the profiles.

#### Actual answer

1. Go to `Settings | Edit Current Profile... | Appearance`
2. Define new Color Scheme for each of the directories you want to have special background for, e.g. myprofile1, myprofile2, mystandard
3. Make sure you can manually call `konsoleprofile ColorScheme=myprofile1`, `konsoleprofile ColorScheme=standard`, etc.
4. Plug in the calls to `konsoleprofile` into your `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, e.g. add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ "$PWD" = /home/me/src/java* ]] && konsoleprofile ColorScheme=myprofile1 || konsoleprofile ColorScheme=mystandard'";$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```